# Building R Packages using Alternate GCC

Tags: bash, gcc, r

The systems I work with have GCC 4.5 (experimental) in /usr/local/bin/gcc which has proven to be problematic for some R packages. I would like to instead use system GCC in /usr/bin/gcc.

I have tried setting CC and CXX in the Bash configuration files (.bashrc, .bash_profile etc.) as well as on the command line, but although Bash recognizes the change, R does not.

How can I get R to use the version of GCC in /usr/bin instead of the one in /usr/local/bin/?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is not that well documented (e.g. I failed to locate it in either 'R Extension' or 'R Admin' right now) but Brian Ripley mentioned it a few times on the lists.

Basically, at R compile time, settings are registered and the stored in `$R_HOME/etc/Makeconf`.  One possibility is to edit that file directly, but you may not have root privileges or may not want to affect all other users.  So the better may be to create

```
~/.R/Makevars
```

with entries

```
CC=gcc-4.4
CXX=g++-4.4
```

plus whichever optmisation flags etc you want to set. That will the affect all subsequent uses of `R CMD INSTALL` or `R CMD check` or ... that you run.

Other files in `$R_HOME/etc/` can similarly be overridden locally from `~/.R/`.

Comment: With my configuration, certain packages require sudo, so in those cases it is necessary to modify Makeconf. Your solution works!

Comment: $R_HOME is /usr/lib64/R/ for CentOS6

Comment: For a R package (largeViz) installation, we had issues even after adding the CXX variable. In addition to that we had to configure CXX11 variable in the Makevars file. Like this CXX11=g++7

Comment: I'm on a mac, and it won't let me write to a file called .R/Makevars in  my ~/ dir. I keep getting: ~/.R/Makevars" E212: Can't open file for writing

Comment: Maybe you need `mkdir ~/.R` first?  The directory needs to exists before you can write a file in it.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, I used `CXX14=/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/g++` to install `rstan` package.

Comment: For me, I added `CC=gcc-11` and `CXX=g++-11` on Ubuntu 22.04 and it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: @Gejun:  Those versions `gcc-11` and `g++-11` are the default versions on Ubuntu 22.04 so you should not need to set them.  Anyway, we are in the comment section of a 12 1/2 year old question and answer so...  However, `~/.R/Makevars` is still _the_ way to make these selections so if it helped you I am glad to hear that.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for the heads up. I guess you are right. Some packages need gcc-5 and g++-5 to compile and I only have the 11 version. Not sure what to do.

Comment: `Makevars` contents are documented in the "Writing R Extension" manual: <https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars>. I'm not sure where `~/.R/Makevars` specifically is officially documented, but it's mentioned several times in that manual.

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar problem.

What worked for me was to define a project directory (rstudio can do that for you), and then add a `.Renviron` file that modifies the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, to include the directory with the new gcc.
In your case, for example, the `.Renviron` will look something like:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/bin/gcc/lib:/usr/local/bin/gcc/lib64:/usr/local/bin/gcc/libexec:`*other paths*

`PATH=/usr/local/bin/gcc/bin:/usr/local/bin:`*other paths*

Answer (score 2):

Check your path to see if /usr/local/bin comes before /usr/bin.  If it does, just make sure /usr/bin comes first:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:${PATH}
```

(it's okay if /usr/bin is duplicated appears twice).

Comment: Didn't work:
export PATH=/usr/bin:${PATH}
R CMD INSTALL...

checking for gcc... /usr/local/bin/gcc -std=gnu99

Answer (score 1):

Look at `configure.args` part of `?install.packages` and compare this to `./configure --help` on e.g. the r source tree.

You can also, from bash, `CC=clang R CMD INSTALL /path/to/package/source`.

HTH