# R: Installing MonetDBLite 0.2.0 under Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6.7

Tags: r, redhat, monetdb, monetdblite

I am trying to install/compile the MonetDBLite package version 0.2.0 under R version 3.2.1 (the most recent one provided by the cluster on which I am working) on a system running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6.7. However the Intel C++ Compiler stops with the following warning:

```
icc: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-foutput'
icc: error #10236: File not found:  'libmonetdb5.so'
```

I guess the problem starts a bit earlier with the following warnings:

```
Makefile:1032: warning: overriding commands for target `all'
Makefile:523: warning: ignoring old commands for target `all'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/scratch/Rtmp4Nlu3l/R.INSTALL6e966e9f4376/MonetDBLite/src'
/opt/bwhpc/common/math/R/3.2.1-mkl-11.2.3-intel-15.0/lib64/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB --output libmonetdb5.so -Wl,--whole-archive `find buildtools common clients gdk monetdb5 sql tools -name "*.o" | xargs echo` -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lz -lpcre
make[2]: Entering directory `/scratch/Rtmp4Nlu3l/R.INSTALL6e966e9f4376/MonetDBLite/src'
icc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/opt/bwhpc/common/math/R/3.2.1-mkl-11.2.3-intel-15.0/lib64/R/lib 

(...)

icc: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-foutput'
icc: error #10236: File not found:  'libmonetdb5.so
```

I'm not sure whether the libmonetdb5.so file gets written into the wrong directory and then cannot be accessed by the compiler that gets started in a deeper directory. However, even if that would be the case I have no clue how to fix this, so I would be grateful for any suggestions about the causes of this problem and how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say please don't use icc for MonetDBLite.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it even though it required to force R to use gcc using this "trick": 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616983/building-r-packages-using-alternate-gcc

Simply using `configure.args=c(CC="gcc")` did not suffice.