# R :: override C compiler using Makevars

Tags: r

Our R installation define in:

```
R$HOME/etc/Makeconf that CC = gcc -std=gnu99
```

I have one specific package (mix of C++ and C code) that need to be compiled using

```
  CC = gcc
```

without `-std=gnu99`

As far as I understood I have 3 ways of doing that:
1) system wide, edit R$HOME/etc/Makeconf
2) per user basis, play with ~/.R/Makevars
3) per package basis, set PACKAGE/src/Makevars

Even if 1 and 2 is not what I want I tested the 3 options, using 1 and 2

`R CMD INSTALL -l pack.tgz` is OK "gcc -std=gnu99" is corectly replaced by "gcc"

But when using `PACKAGE/src/Makevars` approach it fails

I must admit that I'm lost at this point, where should I look ?

edit. 
this is not really a duplicate with [Building R Packages using Alternate GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616983/building-r-packages-using-alternate-gcc)
for sure I have read the previous one.is the one that pointed me to Makevars

my key concern is that **PACKAGE/src/Makevars** is not taken in account for CC=alternate compiler while other one are working prefectly.

Comment: Dirk's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616983/building-r-packages-using-alternate-gcc points to #2 (and, implicitly, #1) as the likely solution as does http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html.

Comment: This is still not as clear or obvious as we would like it to be but between your question here and my earlier answer I think we have all bases covered.

Comment: maybee this can help to understand. if ~/.R/Makevars contains CC=gcc, then R CMD SHLIB *.c compiles using gcc. - if no ~/.R/Makevars and CC=gcc in PACK/src/Makevars then R CMD SHLIB *.c compiles using gcc -std=gnu99 (ie the value of R CMD config CC) that let me say that PACK/src/Makevars is ignored, at least for CC definition.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in fortran. Anyway I made a model of your package and I found an half solution. It seems that not all the variables in `PACKAGE/src/Makevars` are considered and used. In order to make it work I used this `Makevars` file:

```
MY_PKG_LIBS =
MY_PKG_CCLAGS = -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g

all: $(SHLIB)                      
hello.o: hello.c
        gcc $(MY_PKG_CCLAGS) -c hello.c -o hello.o $(MY_PKG_LIBS)

PKG_LIB = -std=gnu++11
```

Obviously the `hello.c` file should be replaced by `your_file_name.c`. If you can not change the `CC` and you adopt my workaround, the real problem become that when the shared file `.so` is created, the compiler flags should be overwritten using `PKG_CFLAGS` or `PKG_CPPFLAGS` as stated in [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) (again in the `Makevars` file). In my personal situation (Ubuntu 15.04, R 3.1.2), I tried those and other vars following the guidelines in `/etc/R/Makeconf` file:

```
ALL_CFLAGS = $(R_XTRA_CFLAGS) $(PKG_CFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
ALL_CPPFLAGS = $(R_XTRA_CPPFLAGS) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CLINK_CPPFLAGS)
```

The only thing that worked in adding a flag to the `-shared` final compiling of the package was adding the library linker flag (As I did originally with my fortran code) `PKG_LIB = -std=gnu++11` in the `PACKAGE/src/Makevars`. 
My final result in installing the package is:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘question1’ ...
** libs
gcc -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c hello.c -o hello.o 
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o question1.so hello.o -std=gnu++11 -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/dgarolini/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/question1/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (question1)
```