# Error install package "kohonen" package for R

Tags: r, installation, package, failed-installation

I tried to install the package "kohonen" and that is the output when trying to lauchn it

```
> require(kohonen)
Le chargement a nécessité le package : kohonen
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘kohonen’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 impossible de charger l'objet partagé '/home/sebastien/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
  ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so: symbol _ZTTNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

I tried to figure out what is going but I didn't find how to fix it. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04

I saw it may be fixed by downgrading gcc to 4.x (maybe 4.2, since the package sucessfully installed on my latpopo with this gcc version)

Current version is:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Homebrew gcc 5.4.0) 5.4.0
```

I saw you can have several gcc versions installed, but I dont know how to specify the gcc used by R.

---

EDIT
I tried using gcc 4.8 and R uses it. But it didn't solve my problem...

---

EDIT 2

It may be due to GLIBCXX_3.4.21 and libstdc++.so.6 with

But I have GLIBCC3.4.21

```
sebastien@sebastien-LABOFARM-HP-Z640-Workstation:~/.R$ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
```

---

```
sebastien@sebastien-LABOFARM-HP-Z640-Workstation:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ll libstdc*
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      19 août  20 21:01 libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.24*
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1114368 août  20 21:15 libstdc++.so.6.0.24*
```

---

I finally checked my laptop where the kohonen package works and i found this:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1471104 12 mar  2016 libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       21 28 oct  2015 libstdc++.6.dylib -> libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       17 28 oct  2015 libstdc++.dylib -> libstdc++.6.dylib
```

So basicallyI think my issue is libstdc++ is older so the package won't work.
I have tried to update gcc but it doesn't update libstdc++

Comment: Or you can try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616983/building-r-packages-using-alternate-gcc

Answer (score 0):

Ok now some of my R packages cannot be load any more.

The error is the same; I'm lost

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it seems my last error fix the original errors.

I just deleted every user installed R packages.

And then I reinstall some packages, including kohonen and it works.

Maybe some packages (dependencies from kohonen) were compiled with different gcc version compiler and it brokes everything