# Package build ignores Makevars flags

Tags: c++, r, r-package

### Question

I'm trying to tell my package to use `gcc` to compile the `C++` code in stead of `clang`. Why aren't my `CXX` flags in my `Makevars` file being used?

(I am expecting/hoping the solution to be something really simple that I've overlooked.)

---

It's my understanding (see **references**) that I can specify `CXX*` flags in either

1. `src/Makevars` in the package, or
2. `~/.R/Makevars`

However, I can't get option 1 to work, only option 2.

#### Example Builds

Here are screenshots showing the build options I'm using. In each case I'm showing both the `Makevars` and the `/.R/Makevars` files to show which one I'm using in each case.

**Option 1: `src/Makevars`**

Here I specify `CXX11 = /usr/local/bin/g++-7` inside `src/Makevars`. The build messages say it's building with `clang`

[image]

**Option 2: ~/.R/Makevars**

Here I specify `CXX11 = /usr/local/bin/g++-7` inside `~/.R/Makevars`. The build message shows it builds with `g++`

[image]

### Example package

I've noticed this on a few packages I've built recently using `Rcpp`, but if you want an example to test my `googlePolylines` package is [here on github](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googlePolylines).

---

### References

- [Building R packages using Alternate GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1618618/5977215)
- [Understanding the contents of Makevars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43599233/5977215)

### Session Info

```
devtools::session_info()
Session info ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
 system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        ## Mac OS
 ui       RStudio (1.1.414)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_AU.UTF-8                 
 tz       Australia/Melbourne         
 date     2018-03-11
```

Comment: Your package mustn’t override the C++ compiler(/version) used to compile packages. Otherwise R wouldn’t be able to load it. Hence R forbids this. For the same reason your R package distribution (on GitHub) shouldn’t include the `src/*.o` files.

Comment: right! I hadn't correctly set up the `.gitignore` and those `.o`s were committed erroneously. I've now cleand up the github repo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting Duncan Murdoch in https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2017q4/002087.html:

> According to section 1.2.1 "Using Makevars" in Writing R Extensions, 
>   R_HOME/etcR_ARCH/Makeconf is included after Makevars, so what you're 
>   seeing is by design. I believe this is so that packages are built with 
>   tools compatible with those that built R.  (Remember, packages are 
>   designed for distribution to diverse systems.)

So you might change various flags within `src/Makevars` via for example `PKG_CXXFLAGS`, but you cannot overwrite `CXXFLAGS` or `CXX` itself. And there is no `PKG_CXX`.