# Writing `configure` file for an r package

Tags: autoconf, r-package, sbml

I am writing an r package which provides a wrapper around the `libSBML` C [library](http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML).

I am using the `rcppgsl` [package](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppgsl) as a reference, which looks for the location of header files and the library files for GNU Scientific Library `GSL` and uses that information to write the `configure` script and `Makevars` and `Makevars.in`. I am not building for Windows currently. On my machine (macOS), `libsbml` (SBML C library) is installed in usual locations, i.e.

header files are at - `/usr/local/include/sbml`

and library files at - `/usr/local/lib`. Indeed, if in my package `Makevars` file I use the following, I can build my [package](https://github.com/sn248/Rcppsbml).

```
CXX=clang++
PKG_CPPFLAGS= -I/usr/local/include
PKG_LIBS= $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) /usr/local/lib/libsbml-static.a
```

However, I want to learn how to use the `configure` script to find the library and use that information to build the package. The relevant portion of `configure.ac` from `rcppgsl` is

```
## Check for non-standard programs: gsl-config(1)
AC_PATH_PROG([GSL_CONFIG], [gsl-config])
## If gsl-config was found, let's use it
if test "${GSL_CONFIG}" != ""; then
    # Use gsl-config for header and linker arguments
    GSL_CFLAGS=`${GSL_CONFIG} --cflags`
    GSL_LIBS=`${GSL_CONFIG} --libs`
else
    AC_MSG_ERROR([gsl-config not found, is GSL installed?])
fi
```

I replaced `GSL_CONFIG` with `LIB_SBML` at relevant places, i.e., the entire `configure.ac` file I am using is pasted below (at the end).

However, I don't see `configure`, `Makevars` and `Makevars.in` being generated (which I see in `rcppgsl`). Any help here would be highly appreciated!

For the sake of completion, the output of 
`ls -l | grep sbml` (in `usr/local/include`) is

```
drwxrwxr-x   58 root      admin    1856 Aug  1  2016 sbml
```

and `ls -l | grep sbml` (in `usr/local/lib`) is

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root      wheel   7970584 Aug  2  2016 libsbml-static.a
-rwxr-xr-x   1 arcadmin  staff  10453624 Nov 25  2014 libsbml.5.11.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root      wheel   3813572 Aug  2  2016 libsbml.5.13.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      wheel        20 Aug  1  2016 libsbml.5.dylib -> libsbml.5.13.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root      wheel  13907656 Feb 26  2015 libsbml.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 arcadmin  staff        15 Mar 27  2015 libsbml.dylib -> libsbml.5.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root      wheel       828 Feb 26  2015 libsbml.la
-rwxrwxr-x   1 root      admin  13362732 Nov 25  2014 libsbmlj.jnilib
```

My `configure.ac` file --

```
## Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.
##
## Configure.ac for RcppSBML
##
## Copyright (C) 2010         Romain Francois and Dirk Eddelbuettel
## Copyright (C) 2014 - 2015  Dirk Eddelbuettel
##
## Licensed under GNU GPL 2 or later

# The version set here will propagate to other files from here
AC_INIT([Rcppsbml], 0.1.0)

# Checks for common programs using default macros
AC_PROG_CC

## Use gsl-config to find arguments for compiler and linker flags
##
## Check for non-standard programs: gsl-config(1)
AC_PATH_PROG([LIB_SBML], [libsbml])
## If gsl-config was found, let's use it
if test "${LIB_SBML}" != ""; then
    # Use gsl-config for header and linker arguments
    SBML_CFLAGS=`${LIB_SBML} --cflags`
    SBML_LIBS=`${LIB_SBML} --libs`
else
    AC_MSG_ERROR([libsbml not found, is SBML installed?])
fi

# Now substitute these variables in src/Makevars.in to create src/Makevars
AC_SUBST(LIB_SBML)
AC_SUBST(LIB_SBML)

AC_OUTPUT(src/Makevars)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here a minimal setup:

Remove `src/Makevars` and create `src/Makevars.in` with content

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS= @SBML_INCLUDE@
PKG_LIBS= $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) @SBML_LIBS@
```

I am not setting `CXX` since you cannot change that in `src/Makevars`, c.f. [Package build ignores Makevars flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217539/package-build-ignores-makevars-flags/49239581#49239581).

Create a minimal `configure.ac` file:

```
AC_INIT([Rcppsbml], 0.1.0)

AC_LANG(C++)
AC_REQUIRE_CPP
AC_PROG_CXX

# default values
AC_SUBST([SMBL_INCLUDE], "-I/usr/local/include")
AC_SUBST([SMBL_LIBS], "/usr/local/lib/libsbml-static.a")

# allow for override
AC_ARG_WITH([smbl],
            AC_HELP_STRING([--with-smbl=PREFIX],
                           [path to where smbl is installed]),
            [
             SMBL_INCLUDE="-I${with_smbl}/include"
             SMBL_LIBS="${with_smbl}/lib/libsbml-static.a"
            ],
            [])

# create and report output
AC_CONFIG_FILES([src/Makevars])
AC_OUTPUT
echo
echo "Final src/Makevars"
cat src/Makevars
```

Call `autoconf` to create a `configure` file from your `configure.ac` template. You might want to check the script with `./configure` and `./configure --with-smbl=/some/path`.

Call

```
R CMD build ...
R CMD check [--install-args=--configure-args=--with-smbl=/some/path] ...
R CMD INSTALL [--configure-args=--with-smbl=/some/path]...
```

to build, check and install the package.

Possible extensions:

- Allow for switching between static and dynamic linking.
- Check that SMBL can be found in a usable state at the specified location.

---

I see three issues here:

- The generation of `configure` from `configure.ac` is *not automatic*. You have to call `autoconf`.
- Similarly, `Makevars.in` is not generated by the system. You have to provide it as template from which `Makevars` is generated by `configure`.
- The GSL ships with `gsl-config`, other libraries make use of the general `pkg-config`. If your library does not support this, you can use the more traditional way to use default locations or those provided with `--with-...` arguments. For example in [RcppArrayFire I use](https://github.com/daqana/rcpparrayfire/blob/master/configure.ac#L50-L54):

  ```
  AC_SUBST([AF_INCLUDE], "")
  AC_SUBST([AF_LIBS], "-laf")

  AS_IF([test -e "${with_arrayfire}"],
          [
           AF_INCLUDE="-I${with_arrayfire}/include ${AF_INCLUDE}"
           AF_LIBS="-L${with_arrayfire}/lib ${AF_LIBS} -Wl,-rpath,${with_arrayfire}/lib"
          ])
  ```

  If a directory is supplied as `--with-arrayfire=/relevant/path`, then appropriate sub directories are searched for headers and dynamic libraries.

Comment: Wow, thanks! There is so much here that I don't know (e.g., how to use `autoconf` while building a package, but thanks for the pointers. I will search for a step by step procedure, but would you be kind to add a little more details here?

Comment: @ Ralf Stubner, Thanks!, I will give this a go and let you know the result. `autoconf` is very new to me but thanks for your detailed answer!

Comment: Just want to add that there a very useful tutorial available about `autoconf` and `configure` for package developers at https://unconj.ca/blog/an-autoconf-primer-for-r-package-authors.html